# Error de conexion de MongoDB Compass con mongo Atlas

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Tengo instalado el MongoDb Compas para conectarme a una base de datos creada en https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/database, el link de enlace es el siguiente:

```
mongodb+srv://juangs:<password>@miclustercafe.axzmrxx.mongodb.net/cafeDB?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1
```

En ocasiones se conecta sin problemas, pero la mayoría de las veces da el siguiente error:

> `queryTxt ETIMEOUT miclustercafe.axzmrxx.mongodb.net`

Ya probé el puerto 27027 que según estuve buscando es el que usa mongoDb compass y el puerto está abierto.

Igual sucede cuando intento conectarme desde el VS Code

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Si *a veces conecta* y otra no, parece un problema de latencia de red y no de Mongo Compass o del servicio de Atlas. Si desde la interfaz web (Mongo Atlas) puedes conectarte a tu Servidor, entonces deberías revisar tu versión de Compass y tu red, probablemente sea un problema temporal de la red o si es persistente deberías hacer revisar tu conexión. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio Contreras, al parecer era eso mismo que dices debido a que tengo una conexion a internet por datos moviles y esos dias estuvo bastante inestable. Despues de eso me se ha conectado sin problemas. Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error de conexión lo da en ocaciones por problemas de latencia de la red, pero la forma en la que mejor me he podido conectar es utilizando la VPN CloudFlare. Aun cuando la red esta algo inestable, la conexión es casi instantánea cuando tengo el VPN activo.